# error de indices php

Tags: php, array, csv, matrices

Tengo una matriz irregular, y necesito imprimirla en un csv, el problema es que son 6 columnas y hay filas de la matriz que tienen menos columnas, por ende me arroja error de indices, yo lo estoy haciendo asi:

```
$linea="ESPECIALIDAD;CUPS1;CUPS2;CUPS3;CUPS4;CUPS5;CUPS6;PROCEDIMIENTO";
fwrite($l,$linea);
$sep=';';
$limitador=',';
//consulta base de datos
if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta))
{
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_array())
{
$cupsSeparados = explode($limitador, $fila['cups']);
$linea=$fila['especialidad'].$sep.$cupsSeparados[0].$sep.$cupsSeparados[1].$sep.$cupsSeparados[2].$sep.$cupsSeparados[3].$sep.$cupsSeparados[4].$sep.$cupsSeparados[5].$fila['procedimiento']."\r\n";
fwrite($l,$linea);
}
```

No se como recorrerla para que no me genere ese error sin afectar la cantidad de columnas que hay en el csv, ya que tiene mas datos, si la hago dinamica los datos en las columnas posteriores se me van a correr las columnas faltantes, el resultado que me trae es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En el caso de la segunda linea, la matriz solo tiene un dato, por eso me arroja errores de indices en los mas campos

Muchas gracias

Comment: No queda claro qué es lo que quieres. Pon un ejemplo con datos concretos, creo que así se entendería mejor.

Comment: Estas generando un csv, donde cada resultado esta divido por una coma " , " y entiendo que  dentro de ese csv estas escribiendo lo que sale de $cupsSeparados[0] hasta el 5, pero indicas que aveces tiene mas y aveces tiene menos y te sale un error, cuando te sale el error te pone en el .csv ERROR etc..? podrias indicar el resultado que te esta dando y que es lo que quieres ;)

Comment: Edite la pregunta pra añadir el resultado que me arroja, el csv si se genera, pero en los casos que el arreglo solo tiene un dato es que me arroja el error, la linea del csv esta separada por punto y coma, el problema es que el campo en la bd tiene los resultados y esta separado por comas, para eso utilizo la variable limitador y separar ese campo para crear el arreglo

Comment: podrias agregar parte de los datos de entrada y cual seria el resultado esperado....

Comment: Podrías usar `$linea = implode($sep, $cupsSeparados);` ([Referencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php)) o, incluso, simplemente remplazar las comas con `str_replace($limitador, $sep, $fila['cups']);` y así no involucras índices.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar estas las líneas: `$cupsSeparados = explode($limitador, $fila['cups']);` y `$linea=$cupsSeparados[0].$sep.$cupsSeparados[1].$sep.$cupsSeparados[2].$sep.$cupsSeparados[3].$sep.$cupsSeparados[4].$sep.$cupsSeparados[5]."\r\n";` por esto solamente: **`$linea = implode(";",explode($limitador, $fila['cups']))."\r\n";`** Y luego escribes `$linea` como lo estás haciendo: **`fwrite($l,$linea);`** Aunque lo más simples sería sustituir un separador por otro como comenta @Triby

Comment: Si, entiendo por que no se entiende la pregunta, la cuestion es que tengo datos antes y despues de la matriz de cups (ya edite el codigo de la pregunta para colocar estos campos), mi preocupacion es que haciendolo de esta manera cuando trae menos de 6 cups, el campo de procedimiento se me va correr y ocupara el espacio vacio, por eso cree la matriz de tamaño estatico. no se si me hice entender

Comment: facil si usas un `foreach($dato as $indice => $valor)` puedes verifica si el índice existe antes de entrar al verificar el valor....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esto es lo que necesitas:

```
$linea = "ESPECIALIDAD;CUPS1;CUPS2;CUPS3;CUPS4;CUPS5;CUPS6;PROCEDIMIENTO";

fwrite($l, $linea);

$sep = ';';
$limitador = ',';

//consulta base de datos
if($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {
    while($fila = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
        $cupsSeparados = explode($limitador, $fila['cups']);
        $arregloCups = array_merge($cupsSeparados, array_fill(0, 6 - count($cupsSeparados), ''));

        $linea = $fila['especialidad'] . $sep . implode($sep, $arregloCups) . $sep . $fila['procedimiento'] . "\r\n";

        fwrite($l, $linea);
    }
}
```

Salida de ejemplo, una fila de base de datos queda parseada de la siguiente manera para guardar en el archivo csv:

```
CIRUGÍA GENERAL;531001;;;;;;HERNIORAR
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, me funciono a la maravilla

Comment: De nada, me alegro que te haya servido!